# xsd:dateTime to Java OffsetDateTime

Tags: xml, datetime, xsd, jaxb, java-8

In order to properly handle an [xs:dateTime](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) with JAXB, I have to write my own converter from `String`->[`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

As mentioned in the XML Schema Definition, dateTime was inspired by ISO 8601. I used `OffsetDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)` to parse the `xs:dateTime`, which works fine for e.g.

```
"2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00" //or
"2007-12-03T10:15:30Z"
```

Sadly, in `xs:dateTime` the offset part [is declared optional](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-lexical-representation), so parsing the valid

```
"2016-03-02T17:09:55"
```

throws an `DateTimeParseException`.

**Is there a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for OffsetDateTime, which also handles unzoned `xs:dateTime`s (probably with a default timezone)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in one but you can make your own with the help of the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) class.

You can specify an optional offset enclosed in squared brackets, i.e. `[XXXXX]` (to match `"+HH:MM:ss"`), Then, you can provide a default offset ([`parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-)) in the case where it is not present. If you want to default to UTC, you can set 0 to specify no offset; and if you want to default to the current offset of the VM, you can get it with `OffsetDateTime.now().getLong(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] dates = {
        "2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00",
        "2007-12-03T10:15:30Z",
        "2016-03-02T17:09:55",
        "2016-03-02T17:09:55Z"
    };
    DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXXXX]")
                                      .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
                                      // or OffsetDateTime.now().getLong(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS)
                                      .toFormatter();
    for (String date : dates) {
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(date, formatter));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But isn't it odd that we all have to do this?  Why does the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) have no standard patterns for `xs:date`. `xs:dateTime` and `xs:time` ?

Comment: Actually, I think the correct pattern for `xs:dateTime` is `[XXX]` (3 Xs instead of 5 Xs) because `xs:dateTime` doesn't allow for a seconds-based zone offset.

Comment: @b4hand: or 6 since +01:00 is 6 characters ;-)

Comment: No, quoting from the documentation, you should use only 3 Xs. `XXX` is equivalent to `appendOffset("+HH:MM","Z")`. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern(java.lang.String)

Comment: Beware that using the local time zone offset with this has issues with DST.
If the time in the string was in DST and the current time is not or vice versa, that offset is off by an hour (usually). For example, if you're in central europe and it's currently summertime, the offset of OffsetDateTime.now() is 2 hours, when it should be one hour for dates outside summertime.
The answer by Stefan K doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

just to show my current solution which resolves the unzoned format to the systems default **offset at the currently in parse dateTime**.

```
public static OffsetDateTime parseDateTime(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        try { // try to handle zoneless xml dateTime
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
            ZoneOffset offset = ZoneId.systemDefault().getRules().getOffset(localDateTime);
            return OffsetDateTime.of(localDateTime.toLocalDate(), localDateTime.toLocalTime(), offset);
        } catch (Exception fallbackTryException) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so when the offset is missing, you interpret the date-time in your JVM’s time zone. I think I’d use `localDateTIme.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime()`. Isn’t it a bit easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

The [jTextTime](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTextTime) library solves this. This is a minimal no-dep library available from Maven Central. It handles the case of the missing timezone offset.

The library includes prebuild `XmlAdapters` so you can just annotate your classes with those as in the example below:

```
public class Customer {

    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OffsetDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime")
    public OffsetDateTime getLastOrderTime() {
        ....
    }

    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(OffsetDateXmlAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
    public OffsetDateTime getDateOfBirth() {   // returns a date-only value
        ....
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can do the annotation at the package level so that you don't have to do it for every class and every attribute.

If you are unhappy with the library's default handling of the case of the missing timezone offset then you can [customize](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTexttime/wiki/JAXB-type-adapter-classes-for-java.time#dealing-with-a-missing-timezone-offset).

Full disclosure: I'm the author of jTextTime.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Tunaki's answer as I mentioned in my comment because `xs:dateTime` doesn't allow for a seconds-based zone offset. The correct pattern should only include `[XXX]` based on the documentation of [appendPattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern(java.lang.String)):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
    .toFormatter();
```

Which lists the following table for the timezone format:

```
  Pattern  Count  Equivalent builder methods
  -------  -----  --------------------------
    O       1      appendLocalizedOffset(TextStyle.SHORT)
    OOOO    4      appendLocalizedOffset(TextStyle.FULL)
    X       1      appendOffset("+HHmm","Z")
    XX      2      appendOffset("+HHMM","Z")
    XXX     3      appendOffset("+HH:MM","Z")
    XXXX    4      appendOffset("+HHMMss","Z")
    XXXXX   5      appendOffset("+HH:MM:ss","Z")
    x       1      appendOffset("+HHmm","+00")
    xx      2      appendOffset("+HHMM","+0000")
    xxx     3      appendOffset("+HH:MM","+00:00")
    xxxx    4      appendOffset("+HHMMss","+0000")
    xxxxx   5      appendOffset("+HH:MM:ss","+00:00")
    Z       1      appendOffset("+HHMM","+0000")
    ZZ      2      appendOffset("+HHMM","+0000")
    ZZZ     3      appendOffset("+HHMM","+0000")
    ZZZZ    4      appendLocalizedOffset(TextStyle.FULL)
    ZZZZZ   5      appendOffset("+HH:MM:ss","Z")
```